# NtQueryObject function returns length as -8

Tags: c#, winapi, memory

I'm using `NtQueryObject(handle, OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS.ObjectTypeInformation, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out length);` in my program, but this executes returning length as -8...which is weird;  I don't see how a buffer size can be negative.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I may correct it?

Thanks!

**NB:**

I imported the NtQueryObject using:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
internal static extern NT_STATUS NtQueryObject(
[In] IntPtr Handle,
[In] OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS ObjectInformationClass,
[In] IntPtr ObjectInformation,
[In] int ObjectInformationLength,
[Out] out uint ReturnLength);
```

Comment: According the result of the function is a NTSTATUS - what is the result ?

Comment: There are two potential causes. [An actual defect that should now be fixed](https://web.archive.org/web/20220808124049/https://wj32.org/wp/2012/11/30/obquerytypeinfo-and-ntqueryobject-buffer-overrun-in-windows-8/) or an issue introduced by running via [WOW64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72785103/476371). It's not clear from your question, though, which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have changed the `out` to `ref` like this.

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength, ref int returnLength);
```

The problems seemed to have been from how I was making the call however. The correct way is:

```
NtQueryObject(pHandle, (int)ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation, pBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

That last parameter is supposed to be an unsigned long, so you must have it declared as simply `long` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score -1):

This can occur if you encounter an invalid handle, typically if the handle refers to a network resource that is no longer available.

Check that the NtQueryObject() return status is what you expect.

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// An invalid HANDLE was specified.
//
#define STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE            ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000008L)    // winnt
```